Flutter Widget test: Page not updating after a button tap that invokes notifyListeners() from a mocked service class
I'm writing a Flutter widget test where I need to verify counter values before and after a button tap. Initially, the page correctly displays the value 0. However, after the button tap, the page doesn't update to show the new value 1. It seems that the widget isn't rebuilding as expected, even though notifyListeners() is being called.
The counter increment logic is in a service class, which I've mocked using mockito to return 1 when the button is tapped. I've confirmed that notifyListeners() is being called, but the UI doesn't reflect the change.
Sample Code:
Counter Page:
class CounterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CounterPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CounterPage> createState() => _CounterPageState();
}

class _CounterPageState extends State<CounterPage> {
  late ICounterService _testService;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _testService = Provider.of<ICounterService>(context);
    _testService.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_testService.testValue.toString()),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _testService.incrementValue(null);
          },
          child: const Text('Change value'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Test file:
void main() {
  late ICounterService mockCounterService;

  setUp(() {
    mockCounterService = MockICounterService();

    when(mockCounterService.testValue).thenReturn(0);
    when(mockCounterService.incrementValue(null)).thenAnswer((_) {
      when(mockCounterService.testValue).thenReturn(1);
      mockCounterService.notifyListeners();
    });
  });

  testWidgets('Widget tests for counter page', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ICounterService>(
            create: (_) => mockCounterService,
          ),
        ],
        child: const MaterialApp(
          home: CounterPage(),
        ),
      ),
    );

    expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);

    var changeValueText = find.text('Change value');
    expect(changeValueText, findsOneWidget);

    await tester.tap(changeValueText);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}

What could be causing the widget not to rebuild, and how can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Tried pump(), pumpAndSettle() and called pump with different Duration values. The line
expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
fails all the time.
Code for the ChangeNotifierProvider:
import 'package:counter_application/interfaces/i_counter_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterService extends ChangeNotifier implements ICounterService {


  int _testValue = 0;

  @override
  int get testValue => _testValue;

  @override
  void incrementValue(int? value) {
    _testValue += value ?? 1;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}


please move the when blocks from setUp and  keep it inside the testWidgets before pumping and try.
Also try giving a duration of 2 seconds inside the pumpAndSettle like await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 2));

Thanks for your suggestions! I followed your steps, but the page still didn't rebuild.
I then tried extending ICounterService directly in my test file instead of mocking:
class CustomCounterService extends ICounterService {
int _counter = 0;
@ override
int get testValue => counter;
@override
void incrementValue() {
_counter++;
notifyListeners();  // This triggers the real ChangeNotifier.notifyListeners()
}

This worked, and notifyListeners() triggered the UI rebuild. But with Mockito, notifyListeners() is intercepted by the mock, preventing the rebuild.
How can I mock ChangeNotifierProvider with Mockito and still have notifyListeners() correctly rebuild the UI? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Could you please attach the code of provider?

Hi @albert, please find a link to my github repo for this app.
https://github.com/sumeshthayil/CounterApp
Thanks for your help.

Also, the provider code is added in the question.
